# Skipping the hostkey verification in dput/sftp

Tags: debian, ubuntu, sftp, ppa

I would like to use [dput](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/dput-ng) to upload a package to a launchpad PPA via sftp. After preparing the data, it all works fine until

```
please login: To accept ssh-rsa hostkey 6b03de9833252318a646b34722cd54f2 for ppa.launchpad.net type "yes": [yes, no]:
```

Typing `yes` does the trick, but is impossible to do as a cronjob.

How to skip the hostkey verification in dput?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dput-ng` is using `python-paramiko`, which is not using the OpenSSH (therefore the `~/.ssh/config` changes are not reflected -- out of the question is also the hints to disable strict host key checking when it is your only way to verify you are connecting to the host you think). But it is using the [OpenSSH known hosts](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dput-ng/blob/master/dput/uploaders/sftp.py#L189) store, so you should be able to download the server host keys using ssh-keyscan, **verify them manually**, store them into this store and then connect without any problems:

```
$ ssh-keyscan ppa.launchpad.net
# ppa.launchpad.net:22 SSH-2.0-Twisted
ppa.launchpad.net ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA0aKz5UTUndYgIGG7dQBV+HaeuEZJ2xPHo2DS2iSKvUL4xNMSAY4UguNW+pX56nAQmZKIZZ8MaEvSj6zMEDiq6HFfn5JcTlM80UwlnyKe8B8p7Nk06PPQLrnmQt5fh0HmEcZx+JU9TZsfCHPnX7MNz4ELfZE6cFsclClrKim3BHUIGq//t93DllB+h4O9LHjEUsQ1Sr63irDLSutkLJD6RXchjROXkNirlcNVHH/jwLWR5RcYilNX7S5bIkK8NlWPjsn/8Ua5O7I9/YoE97PpO6i73DTGLh5H9JN/SITwCKBkgSDWUt61uPK3Y11Gty7o2lWsBjhBUm2Y38CBsoGmBw==
```

and paste the line to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Shortcut:

```
$ ssh-keyscan ppa.launchpad.net >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Then you should be able to connect without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Current `dput-ng` has a method called `secure_sftp` that uses `openssh` instead of `paramiko`.

It is not documented, is marked as experimental and not working with `python < 3.2`, but it works for me.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please consider editing your post to include _what version_ you refer to when stating "_Current_ `dput-ng` ..."